# Class too big and hard to add new features

Tags: python

I have a class with like 50 methods.

```
class MyProgram(object):
    def method1(self):
        pass
    def method2(self):
        pass
    # and so on
```

Its that big because my Class is also my program, i call myProgram.py via the console and many methods are options like:

```
myProgram.py --method1 --method2
```

On the one hand it is really easy for me to use the methods like this. On the other hand the code is just not readable anymore. If I have to change two things, I have to go 1000 lines up and then 2000 lines down to just changes some dependencies or add a new feature like method999().

How can I split my class and still have something like myProgramm.py --method1 --method2 ?
Its important that I can call my program like this to do some cronjobs.

(I'm convinced that there is a really easy solution to this, but I just can't think about it now)

EDIT: a better example of my god class.

```
class myprogram(object):
    def __init__(self)
        self.prepare()
    def prepare(self):
        # some initializations
        self.prepareCommands()
    def prepareCommands(self):
        self.initCommand("--updateDatabase", self.updateDatabase)
        self.initCommand("--getImages", self.getImages)
        # and so on
    def initCommand(self, cmd, func):
        options = sys.argv
        for option in options:
            if option.find(cmd)!=-1:
                return func()
    # my commands
    def updateDatabase(self):
        #...
    def getImages(self):
        #...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = myprogram()
```

EDIT2: After researching a little I think I got a good solution. I will update everything when I've rewritten my programm. :)

Comment: You are probably right in your desire to refactor it. It definetly smells like a [god object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)

Comment: Have you already looked at the [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) module?

Comment: wow I never knew about these god objects and as I read the wikipedia article I immediately recognized it as one. I use these kinds of objects very very much....

Comment: @RikPoggi no I didn't have a look. I used a intern method in my god object called "initCommand" to parse these options. I will have a look.

Comment: i don't understand - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960722/how-are-python-command-line-arguments-related-to-methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use an extra level of indirection? (This is an old Computer Science axiom:-)

Edit:

So instead of using the actual method names on the command line, use a dictionary to call the actual code. The dictionary maps the command line 'names' to the actual function or object+method that gets called. Then you would have more flexibility about code structure.

This is only a small part of a solution. Its 'usefulness' is by building the dictionary first, the command line interface is decoupled from the code. Then refactoring the code should be easier, in a test-driven development sense, because the tests and cronjobs won't have to change as the underlying code is restructured. It gives the flexibility to do the restructuring in an iterative and piecemeal way.

(From the comments, it looks like folks knows how to use a dictionary do this).

Comment: Your answers seems to be good, but its too short for me to understand it fully. It would help me alot if you give me a more precisely answer :)

Comment: @xMRW - by Python is not fluent, so it'll take me a while. It is past midnight, so I'll look in the morning. The idea was to map from each word on the command line to a function, so that you can refactor your code without messing up your command line user-interface.  e.g. `{ 'method1': obj1.method17, 'method2': obj7.method9 }`

Comment: oh yes now I understand. Of course this is a good idea, but to do so I have still to refactor most of the code.^^

Comment: Im not a native speaker, of course I want to refactor it, but I was under the impression that this solution of gbulmer is only a little part ;)

Comment: Thank you, you made refactoring my mess alot easier!

Answer (score 3):

Split the functionality across multiple classes. I'm sure you can find functionality in there that can be moved to separate classes and files. In fact, you could even move separate commands to separate files for a start.

You can then import them in the file that's called in the cronjob. It may require a lot of refactoring and rewriting but it'll make the code a lot easier to maintain and extend. You haven't really described what the code does but if you have to move 1000 lines up and 2000 lines down to add some functionality, chances are that code belongs together. And code that belongs together can be refactored and moved.

Answer (score 0):

OK i've done some refactoring and I'm very proud of myself now :D
Its much more readable and much better to maintain:

This is the structure of my application now:

```
./libs # external libs
./data # files my application works with
config.py # settings for all my application, had one before but it was mainly
           # used by the god class to pass down configs, this is now global
commands.py # a command-variable to associate functions from different modules
             # with my command line
myprogram.py # acts more like a commander instead of a god now
#... now come the modules
csv.py # handling things with a essential csv
database.py # of course database
download.py # everything that has to do with downloads
filesys.py # extended file operators
logsys.py # logging system
mysql.py # an extended mysql class
parse.py # parsing
# and so on
```

How does it work?

myprogram.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from config import *
from commands import *

from logsys import log
import filesys

class myprogram(object):   
    __name__ = "myprogram"
    __author__ = "MRW"
    __email__ = "XXX"
    __date__ = "01.04.2012"

    def __init__(self):
        log(_class=self.__name__, _func='__init__', _level=0)
        log(_class=self.__name__, _func='__init__',  text="DEBUG LEVEL %s" % settings["debug"], _level=0)
        self.settings = settings
        self.cmds = commands

    def prepare(self):
        log(_class=self.__name__, _func='prepare', _level=1)
        self.dirs = {}
        for key in settings["dir"].keys():
            self.dirs[key] = settings["dir"][key]
            filesys.checkDir(self.dirs[key])

    def initCommands(self):
        log(_class=self.__name__, _func='initCommands', _level=1)
        options = sys.argv
        for option in options:
            for cmd in self.cmds.keys():
                if option.find(cmd) != -1:
                    return self.cmds[cmd]()


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    p = myprogram()
    p.prepare()
    p.initCommands()
```

commands.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

commands = {}
#csv
import csvsys
commands["--getCSV"] = csvsys.getCSV
#commands["--getCSVSplitted"] = csvsys.getCSVSplitted

# update & insert
import database
commands["--insertPNDB"] = database.insertPNDB
commands["--updatePNDB"] = database.updatePNDB
commands["--insertProductSpecificationPNDB"] = database.insertProductSpecificationPNDB
commands["--updateProductSpecificationPDB"] = database.updateProductSpecificationPDB
commands["--updatePricesPDB"] = database.updatePricesPDB

# download
import download
commands["--downloadProductSites"] = download.downloadProductSites
commands["--downloadImages"] = download.downloadImages

# parse
import parse
commands["--parseProductSites"] = parse.parseProductSites
```

config.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import date

settings = {}

settings["debug"] = 2

# links
settings["link"] = {}
settings["link"]["csv"]    = "http://xxxs/xxx/1"
settings["link"]["search"]    = "http://xxx/?txtSearch1=%s"

# directories
settings["dir"] = {}
settings["dir"] ["root"] = "/media/Xtra/Code/xxx"
settings["dir"]["data"] = settings["dir"]["root"] + "/data/"
settings["dir"]["libs"] = settings["dir"]["root"] + "/libs/"
settings["dir"]["log"] = settings["dir"]["data"] + "/logs/"
settings["dir"]["cache"] = settings["dir"]["data"] + "/cache/"
settings["dir"]["sites"] = settings["dir"]["data"] + "/sites/"
settings["dir"]["parsed"] = settings["dir"]["data"] + "/parsed/"
settings["dir"]["csv"] = settings["dir"]["data"] + "/csv/"
settings["dir"]["images"] = settings["dir"]["data"] + "/images/"

# filenames
settings["filename"] = {}
settings["filename"]["log"] = date.getDate()+".log"
settings["filename"]["parsed"] = "%s.parsed"
settings["filename"]["site"] = "%s.html"
settings["filename"]["image"] = "%s.jpg"
# paths
settings["path"] = {}
settings["path"]["csv"] = settings["dir"]["csv"]+settings["filename"]["csv"]
settings["path"]["log"] = settings["dir"]["log"]+settings["filename"]["log"]
settings["path"]["parsed"] = settings["dir"]["parsed"]+settings["filename"]["parsed"]
settings["path"]["site"] = settings["dir"]["sites"]+settings["filename"]["site"]
settings["path"]["image"] = settings["dir"]["images"]+settings["filename"]["image"]

# database
settings["database"] = {}
settings["database"]["xxx"] = {}
settings["database"]["xxx"]["host"] = "xxx"
settings["database"]["xxx"]["user"] = "xxx"
settings["database"]["xxx"]["passwd"] = "xxx"
settings["database"]["xxx"]["database"] = "xxx"
settings["database"]["xxx2"] = {}
settings["database"]["xxx2"]["host"] = "xxx"
settings["database"]["xxx2"]["user"] = "xxx"
settings["database"]["xxx2"]["passwd"] = "xxx"
settings["database"]["xxx2"]["database"] = "xxx"


# multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
settings["multiprocessing"] = {}
settings["multiprocessing"]["num_consumers"] = cpu_count()*12

# web
settings["web"] = {}
settings["web"]["404"] = ("404 Fehler",  "404 Error",  "404 Not Found", "")
```

So basically I call my programm like this:

```
./myprogram.py --getCSV --downloadProductSites --parseProductSites --uploadSpecification
```