# How are Python command line arguments related to methods?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

Everyone at [Class too big and hard to add new features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960496/class-too-big-and-hard-to-add-new-features) is completely unphased by the question, which somehow connects command line options to methods, but I can find no documentation for this.  It's not `optparse`, or `argparse`, or `sys.argv` - the question implies some kind of direct relationship between methods and command line options.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply use the class like this, what seems not to be a very good idea, because it is very hard to maintain once u got many commands.

```
class myprogram(object):
    def __init__(self)
        self.prepare()
    def prepare(self):
        # some initializations
        self.prepareCommands()
    def prepareCommands(self):
        self.initCommand("--updateDatabase", self.updateDatabase)
        self.initCommand("--getImages", self.getImages)
        # and so on
    def initCommand(self, cmd, func):
        options = sys.argv
        for option in options:
            if option.find(cmd)!=-1:
                return func()
    # my commands
    def updateDatabase(self):
        #...
    def getImages(self):
        #...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = myprogram()
```

EDIT1:
Here a cleaner way I just implemented:

myprogram.py:

```
from config import * # has settings
from commands import *

from logsys import log
import filesys

class myprogram(object):
    def __init__(self):
        log(_class=self.__name__, _func='__init__', _level=0)
        log(_class=self.__name__, _func='__init__',  text="DEBUG LEVEL %s" % settings["debug"], _level=0)
        self.settings = settings
        self.cmds = commands
    def prepare(self):
        log(_class=self.__name__, _func='prepare', _level=1)
        self.dirs = {}
        for key in settings["dir"].keys():
            self.dirs[key] = settings["dir"][key]
            filesys.checkDir(self.dirs[key])

    def initCommands(self):
        log(_class=self.__name__, _func='initCommands', _level=1)
        options = sys.argv
        for option in options:
            for cmd in self.cmds.keys():
                if option.find(cmd) != -1:
                    return self.cmds[cmd]()


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    p = myprogram()
    p.prepare()
    p.initCommands()
```

commands.py:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-



commands = {}
#csv
import csvsys
commands["--getCSV"] = csvsys.getCSV
#commands["--getCSVSplitted"] = csvsys.getCSVSplitted



# update & insert
import database
commands["--insertProductSpecification"] = database.insertProductSpecification


# download
import download
commands["--downloadProductSites"] = download.downloadProductSites
commands["--downloadImages"] = download.downloadImages

# parse
import parse
commands["--parseProductSites"] = parse.parseProductSites
```

EDIT2: I have now updated my question you linked to your question with a more complete example [Class too big and hard to add new features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960496/class-too-big-and-hard-to-add-new-features/9960529#comment12723547_9960529)

Comment: One of the problems wit your example is that it lacks any way to give value to arguments such as --max-val 5 or --treads=5

Comment: yes thats true indeed, but I didn't need specific arguments for my "commands"  because the god class itself knew what to do.^^

Comment: wow, I never thought of doing something like that! Interesting.

Comment: I just added a cleaner way of this method I used. Now my "god class" is more like a "commander" that calls some functions^^

Answer (score 4):

There isn't any set-in-stone link between them. The question you link to appears to be a program that can do one of several different things, with command-line arguments switching between them. These *things* happen to be implemented in the program using methods.

It is implied by the question that they have used something like `argparse` to write the glue between these; but the use of methods is just an implementation detail of the particular program.